# Is it OK for the database to be completely overwritten for many times?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, corruption

A simple and maybe too amateur question, but: is it good for a table on the database to be consistently (for example, every day) completely overwritten?

I get regularly (every day) the data for the whole year from the beginning of the year until now. I could just append the new days to the table, but I fear that there are some new data (adjustions or so) for the past days in the file. So I want to overwrite my table every time I get a new file. But is it ok for the table? I mean can it somehow corrupt it?

Comment: Which database engine and version are you using?

Comment: @JonathanFite mysql 5.6.25, innodb

Comment: The obvious answer is that it should be fine. An RDBMS should not eat your data.

Comment: No, unless perhaps you are using some bizarre method to "overwrite" the table. I assume you'd use normal commands such as `truncate` or `delete from...` before loading in the newest data each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No corruption, no loss, no...  (Well, there is always the remote chance of a hardware failure, software bug, typo on your part, etc.)

Here is a 'better' way to completely reload a table:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
load `new` by whatever means
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

That way, the table, `real`, is always available except for the brief moment when the `RENAME` is running.